# Mysql - How to get all descendants(even grandchildren and so on..) with just the ancestor id?

Tags: mysql

I do want to get all the descendants(including grandchildren) id from my tree where I'll just input the parent id. I currently use closure table as my approach. I have this table for storing the parent and child id:

```
CREATE TABLE `treepaths` (
`ancestor` int(11) NOT NULL,
`descendant` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ancestor`,`descendant`),
KEY `FK_Descendant_idx` (`descendant`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_Ancestor` FOREIGN KEY (`ancestor`) REFERENCES `organization` 
(`organization_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Descendant` FOREIGN KEY (`descendant`) REFERENCES 
`organization` (`organization_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is my where I insert my data:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CreateChild`(
Ancestor int,
Descendant int,

ParentID int,
ChildID int
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO treepaths
VALUES (Ancestor, Descendant);
SELECT tree.ancestor, ChildID FROM treepaths tree
WHERE tree.descendant = ParentID
UNION ALL SELECT ChildID, ChildID; 
END
```

And this where I read the data:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetOrganizationDescendant`(
Ancestor int
)
BEGIN
SELECT org.* FROM organization org 
JOIN treepaths tree ON org.organization_id = tree.descendant
WHERE tree.ancestor = Ancestor;
END
```

Currently, it only retrieve the direct child of the parent, not it's grandchildren. Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**
I revise my table with adjacency list model using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/4711741) as reference. Now, I wanted to include the parent in the table. How do I do this? This is the sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d74210/1) of the reference above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just manipulated it on my source code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you switch to a nested set model for hierarchies / trees - makes life a **lot** easier for the kinds of queries your trying to run and no doubt will want to run in future

- [Wikipedia Nested-Set-Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)
- [MySQL example](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: sorry for late reply. I already change my approach using adjacency list model. Nested-set model are too complicated for me especially the insertion of data.